# Symfony2 APCu or XCache

Tags: symfony, apc, xcache

I have question. 
What's better for symfony2, **APCu**(PHP 5.6) or **XCache**?
All saying that APC is wrong choice, because it's bugged, etc...

I'm so confused ...

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at OPCache for PHP 5.5 and newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APCu is APC without the code caching (which is now handled by OpCache, which you should have enabled on a production server). It's solid code, because it is based on a very solid codebase, that just does less than its forerunner.

In terms of local data caching, there's very little in it. Depending on the task required, Memcached or Redis can also be useful tools to cache data.